# ERROR: No XAML Found at the location '/Protocol' C# Facebook SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm new to the Facebook SDK

While Using the Single Sign On Facebook SDK for Windows Phone 8. I added the **`<Protocol Name="msft-[AppId]" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />`** in the WMAppManifest.xml file. But When I run the debug the app, it shows an exception the

> "No XAML was found at the location '/Protocol'"

What shall I do to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Protocol under extensions like this:

```
<Extensions> 
  <Protocol Name="msft-[AppId]" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" /> 
</Extensions>
```

[check this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Facebook-Login-for-Windows-fd1048f5)

related blog link is given at last, please check that also.

Answer (score 2):

First of all i don't think the Protocol Name attribute is correct. Based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769509(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_EXTENSIONSelement) about the Protocol Name: The prefix in your custom URI scheme. A string between 2 and 39 characters in length that contains numbers, lowercase letters, periods ('.'), or hyphens ('-'). Do not include the colon (':') or anything else that will follow the prefix in the URI.

Apart from that i beleive you are trying to navigate in a uri that doesn't exist. What i suggest is break in the constructor of your custom uri mapper. You should have a class similar to this

```
public class CustomUriMapper: UriMapperBase
{
    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        // Break into this point to detect the incoming uri and be sure
        // to return a valid xaml page if tempuri contains your protocol name
        string tempUri = uri.ToString();
        string mappedUri = string.Empty;
        // Search for a specific deep link URI keyword
        if (tempUri.Contains("msftappid"))
        {
            // Launch to the mainpage xaml.
            return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        }
        // Otherwise perform normal launch.
        Debug.WriteLine("Normal launch detection");
        return uri;
    }
}
```

Break into constructor to detect the incoming uri and be sure to return a valid xaml page if tempuri contains your protocol name. In your example msft-[AppId] should be **msftappid**.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to App.xaml.cs and into InitializePhoneApplication() insert this code:

```
RootFrame.UriMapper = new CallbackUriMapper();
```

You need this to initialize the callback class. (CallbackUriMapper() is an example. Just put the name you applied to that class).

Answer (score 0):

firstly, FB beta app is invoking your app properly.. and your App.xaml.cs dont know where to redirect the control... hence the error.

Sol:

i. add this line

```
RootFrame.UriMapper = new ContosoCallbackUriMapper();
```

in side your *App.xaml.cs* file in method *InitializePhoneApplication*().

ii. Import this class file ContosoCallbackUriMapper.cs from the sample example downloaded from MSDN page.. [LINK HERE](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Facebook-Login-for-Windows-fd1048f5/file/101131/5/Facebook%20Login%20for%20Windows%20Phone%208.zip)

And add it to you project level.

it should work fine..

if read the code... step 1 tells to use this class for any URI mapping,, n step 2 tells that if State is authenticated, redirect the user to Main.xaml...